# Is it possible to extract in c++ the container template class?

Tags: c++, templates, traits

I was wondering if it is possible to detect the template class container type, and redefine its parameters. For example :

```
typedef std::vector<int> vint;
typedef typeget<vint>::change_param<double> vdouble;
```

Where vdouble would now be an `std::vector<double>`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding on to @Kerrek SB's answer, here is the generic approach:

```
template<typename...> struct rebinder;

template<template<typename...> class Container, typename ... Args>
struct rebinder<Container<Args...>>{
    template<typename ... UArgs>
    using rebind = Container<UArgs...>;
};
```

Which will work for any container under the sun.

Comment: @Benoît because it has value template parameters, this class would have to be modified for that case.

Comment: Hum, I've never though about the fact that typename... was only expanding to types, which is obvious. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can make a simple template rebinder using partial specialization:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template <typename> struct vector_rebinder;

template <typename T, typename A>
struct vector_rebinder<std::vector<T, A>>
{
    template <typename U>
    using rebind =
        std::vector<U,
                    typename std::allocator_traits<A>::template rebind_alloc<U>>;
};
```

Usage:

```
using T1 = std::vector<int>;

using T2 = vector_rebinder<T1>::rebind<double>;
```

Now `T2` is `std::vector<double>`.

Comment: Alas, this only works for vector , the whole idea is to have it for template classes, list , map, mylist, etc... without the rebinder for each of them.

Comment: One thing troubles me, you will change the type of the vector but not the allocator type. At the beginning your vector contains value of type `int` and an allocator of type `std::allocator<int>`. Here you change the value type to double but not the allocator type. which lead to : 
Value type : double
Allocator type : std::allocator<int>
The example http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c8d57b2736947ee shows the error. We have a std::vector<double, std::allocator<int>>

Comment: @Pumkko: Ah yes, that's indeed a terrrible idea. Let me change that.

Comment: @jjknuth: Yes, indeed. It's easy to generalize the pattern a bit using template template parameters. If you're happy to only accept the standard allocator, then it's quite feasible, otherwise it becomes a bit tricky.